# How to display data from 2 tables in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, fetch

**Restaurant Model**

```
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function menus(){
        return $this->hasMany(Menu::class, 'resto_id');
    }
    public function restoimages(){
        return $this->hasOne(RestoImage::class, 'resto_id');
    }
}
```

**RestoImage Model**

```
class RestoImage extends Model
{
    
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['image','resto_id'];
    public function restaurants(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class, 'resto_id');
    }

}
```

**View File**

```
<div class="card mb-4">
<div class="card-body">
    <table id="datatablesSimple">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th colspan="2">Operations</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->id}}</td> 
                <td>{{$item->name}}</td> 
                <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->restoimages->image}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->address}}</td> 
                <td><button><a href="{{route('editresto', $item->id)}}">EDIT</a></button></td>           
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

**RestoController**

```
public function list(){
        $data = Restaurant::with('restoimages')->get();
        $restoimages = RestoImage::all();
        return view('list', compact('data', 'restoimages'));
    }
```

I have 2 tables, one is restaurants and other is resto_images. When an admin inserts new restaurant using a form. Record will be inserted in aboce 2 tables. resto_images table has column resto_id but when I tried to display image from resto_images table, it throws error (Attempt to read property "image" on null). Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There `return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class, 'id');` foreign key is id isn't it? And in line `$item->restoimages->image` I think you should check if there is restoimages or not.

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Yes I tried that way but is shows same error.

Comment: Do all of your restaurants have images ?

Comment: @Atika Yes each restaurant has 1 image

Comment: It is solved now. Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are directly in the `public` folder, then :

```
<td style="width:150px;height:100px;"> //some style to resize images
  @if ($item->restoimages)
     <img src="{{ asset($item->restoimages->image) }}" alt="">
  @else
     <p>no image</p>
  @endif
</td>
```

But if your images are in `public/folderName`, then :

```
<td style="width:150px;height:100px;">
  @if ($item->restoimages)
     <img src="{{ asset('folderName/' . $item->restoimages->image) }}" alt="">
  @else
     <p>no image</p>
  @endif
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your view, you can use the optional function of Laravel or check that there is real value in your relationship with a if,

```
    <td>{{ optional($item->restoimages)->image}}</td>
```

or

```
    <td>{{ $item->restoimages ? $item->restoimages->image : null }}</td>
```

Dont forget the img tag if you want to show the image and css attribute to resize the image.

Comment: I tried 2nd way as you mentioned. But now the output is as below.
620.McD.png
I dont want the name. I want image to be displayed

Comment: Use the img tag.
````
    <td>
        @if ($item->restoimages)
            <img src="{{storage_path($item->restoimages->image)}}" />
        @endif
    </td>
```
If you use another path to store your image in database, you can remove or change storage_path function with public_path or nothing. Just `$item->restoimages->image` if its a link